# \citeauthor from natbib doesn't add a dot behind et al. when citing a source with multiple authors

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

My problem is that \citeauthor from natbib doesn't add a dot behind et al. when citing a source with multiple authors but that is just what is common in papers.

Is there a way to fix \citeauthor that it will add the dot if and only if it adds et al? So that the result includes the dot:

```
John Doe et al.
```

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: @Mico I am using spbasic

Answer (score 1):

The `et al` phrase is hard coded into the `spbasic.bst` file as:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al" }
```

So to add the dot, you should make a copy of the `.bst` file, give it a new name,  and change this to be:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al.\@" }
```

Note that if you are submitting to a journal that requires this style, they may not take kindly to your having changed things.

Comment: Does it mean that they intentionally want me to violate the English language to keep the style of some configuration file? ( https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389956/is-et-al-always-accompanied-by-a-period )

Comment: @baxbear I have no idea. I’m not disagreeing with you that it’s incorrect.